# Как удалить записи старше 10 минут в SQL?

Tags: sql

Такой запрос:

```
"DELETE FROM table WHERE date_add < NOW()-INTERVAL 10 MINUTE"
```

почему-то удаляет запись сразу.

В бд поле date_add вида "2018-10-28 13:21:59".

Как правильно составить запрос?

Comment: запрос правильный. выполните select с аналогичным условием и посмотрите что он выдает. Особое внимание обратите на то, как относится date_add из таблицы и текущий `select now()-INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`. Наверяка у вас в БД данные какие то не те ...

Comment: И кстати фраза '_В бд поле date_add вида "2018-10-28 13:21:59"._' вообще ни о чем не говорит. надо сообщать тип данных колонки. может у вас там вообще строка в таком виде, а со строками как с датами работать невозможно

Comment: @Mike Тип - datetime

Comment: Почему-то в бд попадают записи на 2 часа меньше, чем системное время, может поэтому?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/52ak6QKhEGYMpr

Comment: хотя добавляю так - 'date_add' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

Comment: ну это уже от sql никак не зависит, какие данные кладете, те и получаете. Посмотрите что у вас с датами в том языке из которого вы insert даете. А лучше используйте в insert mysql функцию now() вместо того, что бы дату передавать из клиента